# SQL Server job hangs when calling an SSIS package until agent is restarted

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

I have googled and read many questions/answers, but only one question has ever sounded exactly the same and it did not have an answer.

The situation:

My group has several SQL Servers that are running SQL Server 2017.  They are configured virtually identically.

These servers are build boxes, meaning they pull data from a data ware house, or an extract file, run some ETL processing and then push to a prod box.  SSIS packages are deployed on the box where the DB resides.

Just over a month ago (with no updates having occurred), one of these servers started having an issue where all the jobs that ran an SSIS package would "hang" on the step that ran the package.  Any other step runs fine.  But a job step that runs a package (all jobs do this), will not even start the package.  The package shows no indication in the executions that anything has even tried to start it.

If the user executes the deployed package it will run successfully.

The only thing that will "fix" the issue is restarting the agent service.

I created a simple job to run a simple package every 5 mins.  It had been running for about a week, the last time it ran was 4/11/2021 at 2:40am, the 2:45 run hung.  I could find nothing in the event logs that occurred at that time.  The server was rebooted as a normal scheduled process at 3:15 and was online by 3:25 because that is the next time it tried to run and it again just hung.  So even a server reboot did not fix the issue.

I am at my wits end, since there is no error (the job hangs and the package does not even start) there is no logging that I can find that is showing any issues, I am at a loss as to what might cause this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run [whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases) while the packages are in limbo, what does SQL Server think is happening relative to the job? If you create a new, Hello World equivalent package and schedule it to run every N minutes, do you get the same hanging behaviour?

Comment: It does not see anything running from the job.  And I did set up a simple job like that and it runs every 5 mins and it started hanging sometime between 2:40 and 2:45 (the 2:40 job ran fine, the 2:45 hung).

Comment: Excellent debugging steps. So when it's hung, if you're able to remote into the box, look at Task Manager/Process Explorer. Find any/all dtexec processes that are running and then /shrug try and figure out if they're the one that SSIS is waiting on. I've been running lots of processes on the project deployment model (SSISDB) for nearly a decade now and not experienced what you're running up against. Any chance an anti virus software got installed on the box or updated definitions around the time things went weird? Any SSIS packages using COM objects running about? External programs running?

Comment: Yeah, I have been doing this in this group since SQL 7.0 and have also never seen this behavior.  I have found only one post with lots of googling that really seems to match and it had no answer (most that sound the same have failures or some error to look at).  Something caused it to clear up yesterday so I am trying now to see if something changed that caused that.  I will try your suggestions the next time it happens (it seems to happen at least once per week.

Comment: I have finally found the issue.  We have a job that is using CMDEXEC to unzip a file to file server.  The file already exists and the command is not set to overwrite, so it is hung and for some reason that caused the job steps that execute SSIS packages to hang.  Now I will work with the developer to address this and handle it another way.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SSISDB catalog database on each/all the servers involved. Has it grown exponentially and needs the history etc. cleared down or settings changed? How big are the transaction logs for those databases etc.?

Comment: The SSISDB on that server is only 2GB and is set to unlimited.  The history is only be maintained for a week.  So I do not think that is the issue.